# i make bool condition when i try to use in listveiw i got this error

Tags: flutter, dart, error-handling, dart-null-safety

i make bool condition when i try to use in listveiw i got this error(1 positional argument(s) expected, but 0 found. Try adding the missing arguments.) and when is pass isBool value it gives me this error (Undefined name 'isBool'.
Try correcting the name to one that is defined, or defining the name.)

```
import 'package:chad_cafe/configs/color.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class SigleItem extends StatelessWidget {
  //const SigleItem({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  bool isBool = false;
  SigleItem(this.isBool);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10),
      child: Row(
        children: [
          Expanded(
              child: Container(
            child: Center(
              child: Image.asset('assets/bbqpizza.png'),
            ),
            height: 100,
          )),
          Expanded(
              child: Container(
            height: 100,
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: isBool == false
                  ? MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround
                  : MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                Column(
                  children: [
                    Text(
                      'ProductName',
                      style: TextStyle(
                          color: textColor, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                    ),
                    const Text(
                      'RS-799',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.grey,
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
                isBool == false
                    ? Container(
                        margin: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 15),
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10),
                        height: 35,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          border: Border.all(color: Colors.grey),
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
                        ),
                        child: Row(
                          children: [
                            const Expanded(
                              child: Text(
                                'RS-799',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.grey,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                            Center(
                              child: Icon(
                                Icons.arrow_drop_down,
                                size: 20,
                                color: primaryColor,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      )
                    : const Text('750')
              ],
            ),
          )),
          Expanded(
            child: Container(
                height: 100,
                padding: isBool == false
                    ? EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15, vertical: 32)
                    : EdgeInsets.only(left: 15, right: 15),
                child: isBool == false
                    ? Container(
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          border: Border.all(color: Colors.grey),
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
                        ),
                        child: Center(
                          child: Row(
                            children: [
                              Icon(
                                Icons.add,
                                color: primaryColor,
                                size: 20,
                              ),
                              Text(
                                'Add',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  color: primaryColor,
                                ),
                              )
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      )
                    : Column(
                        children: [
                          const Icon(
                            Icons.delete,
                            size: 30,
                            color: Colors.black,
                          ),
                          const SizedBox(height: 5),
                          Container(
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              border: Border.all(color: Colors.grey),
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
                            ),
                            child: Center(
                              child: Row(
                                children: [
                                  Icon(
                                    Icons.add,
                                    color: primaryColor,
                                    size: 20,
                                  ),
                                  Text(
                                    'Add',
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                      color: primaryColor,
                                    ),
                                  )
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                          )
                        ],
                      )),
          ),
          isBool == false
              ? Container()
              :const Divider(
                  height: 1,
                  color: Colors.black,
                ),
        ],
      ),
    );
    isBool == false
        ? Container()
        : Divider(
            height: 1,
            color: Colors.black,
          );
  }
}





import 'package:chad_cafe/Widgets/single_item.dart';
import 'package:chad_cafe/configs/color.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ReviewCart extends StatelessWidget {
  const ReviewCart({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      bottomNavigationBar: ListTile(
        title: const Text("Total Amount"),
        trailing: Container(
          width: 160,
          child: MaterialButton(
            onPressed: () {},
            child: const Text('Submit '),
            color: primaryColor,
            shape:
                RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30)),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: primaryColor,
        title: const Text(
          'Review Cart',
          style: TextStyle(
            fontSize: 18,
          ),
        ),
      ),
      body: ListView(
        children: [
          const SizedBox(
            height: 10,
          ),
          SigleItem(isBool),//Undefined name 'isBool'.
Try correcting the name to one that is defined, or defining the name.
          const SizedBox(
            height: 10,
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the full code for the widget (less any sensitive info)? This code is incomplete, so we cannot reproduce your issue.

Comment: check now i update it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'isBool' instance belongs to 'SingleItem' class.
And inside your 'ReviewCart' class, you are trying to pass 'isBool'(itself), which is not available in this class, while creating the instance of 'SingleItem' class.

Try passing an actual bool value(true/false) instead of 'isBool' instance.

Answer (score 0):

I think you'e merging your class and widget class, so my best guess is that you should bass a bool parameter to your constructor;

```
 body: ListView(
        children: [
          const SizedBox(
            height: 10,
          ),
          SigleItem(isBool),
          const SizedBox(
            height: 10,
          ),
        ],
      ),
```

If I assumed wrong, please add more information to the question

Comment: this is wrong i am updating my question

Comment: check now i update it

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the variable `isBool` is undefined in the context of the build method for `ReviewCart` - It is only available as a member of an instance of `SingleItem`.

When you construct a new instance of `SingleItem`, you will need to pass it a value which is either a defined variable or a boolean literal:

```dart
class ReviewCart extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      // omitted
      body: ListView(
        children: [
          SingleItem(false); // or true, or some variable which is defined in this context.
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

---

Judging from the name `ReviewCart`, at some point you will probably be building the list from a list of products in the cart - Here's a very simple example of how that might look:

```dart
class ReviewCart extends StatelessWidget {
  List<Product> products;

  ReviewCart(this.products);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      // omitted
      body: ListView(
        children: products.map((product) => 
          SingleItem(product.someBooleanValue)
        ).toList(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```